# Getting Network Data Using Puppeteer: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to intercept file data in the network section of the browser using Puppeteer. I've modified code from the [documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue) (see below) but am receiving the error (after the browser crashes):

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag ...

I'd like to obtain the JSON data without making a separate call the the file explicitly, therefore a fetch of the JSON URL is not an option and have to intercept the data when the browser is launched.

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    page.on('request', (interceptedRequest) => {
        const response = interceptedRequest;

        if (
            response.url().includes('cnni_homepage.json')
        ) {
            console.log(response.body);
            interceptedRequest.continue();
        }
        else { interceptedRequest.abort(); }
    });
    await page.goto("https://edition.cnn.com", { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` is a generic error: you should catch it, then print the real error: `.catch(err => console.error(err))` and share that.

Comment: that parameter to your function is the request, not the response.

Comment: @pguardiario - great catch. I've updated.

Answer (score 0):

The event you are listening to on the page is the 'request', but the one you should be listening to is the 'response' event, because the request event means, as the name sugests, that the browser made a request, but it does not recived a response yet.

unless you are trying to scrap the payload of the request, at line

```
page.on('request', (interceptedRequest) => {
```

it should be

```
page.on('response', (interceptedRequest) => {
```